# Combined diacritics do not normalize with unicodedata.normalize (PYTHON)

Tags: python, unicode, replace, diacritics

I understand that `unicodedata.normalize` converts diacritics to their non diacritic counterparts:

```
import unicodedata
''.join( c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', u'B\u0153uf') 
            if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'
       )
```

My question is (and can be seen in this example): does unicodedata has a way to replace combined char diacritics into their counterparts? (u'œ' becomes 'oe')

If not I assume I will have to put a hit out for these, but then I might as well compile my own dict with all uchars and their counterparts and forget about `unicodedata` altogether...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a bit of confusion about terminology in your question. A [*diacritic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) is a mark that can be added to a letter or other character but generally does not stand on its own. (Unicode also uses the more general term *combining character*.) What `normalize('NFD', ...)` does is to convert [*precomposed characters*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) into their components.

Anyway, the answer is that œ is not a precomposed character. It's a [*typographic ligature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature):

```
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u0153')
'LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE'
```

The `unicodedata` module provides no method for splitting ligatures into their parts. But the data is there in the character names:

```
import re
import unicodedata

_ligature_re = re.compile(r'LATIN (?:(CAPITAL)|SMALL) LIGATURE ([A-Z]{2,})')

def split_ligatures(s):
    """
    Split the ligatures in `s` into their component letters. 
    """
    def untie(l):
        m = _ligature_re.match(unicodedata.name(l))
        if not m: return l
        elif m.group(1): return m.group(2)
        else: return m.group(2).lower()
    return ''.join(untie(l) for l in s)

>>> split_ligatures(u'B\u0153uf \u0132sselmeer \uFB00otogra\uFB00')
u'Boeuf IJsselmeer ffotograff'
```

(Of course you wouldn't do it like this in practice: you'd preprocess the Unicode database to generate a lookup table as you suggest in your question. There aren't all that many ligatures in Unicode.)

Comment: WARNING: The approach based on the Unicode name containing "LIGATURE" is not robust. It appears that some ligatures don't have "LIGATURE" in their name string. For example, unicodedata.name(u'\xc6') -> 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER AE'.

Comment: There's also ß (U+00DF), which is called "LATIN SMALL LETTER SHARP S" but can be thought of as a double-S ligature.

Comment: @ScottH: Would you like me to delete this answer?

Comment: @GarethRees: Keep your answer, it's useful. By my count, unicodedata has over 500 code points with ligature in the name (based on ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/5.2.0/ucd/NamesList.txt), though many of those are for other languages. I just mentioned my warning to let people know there are some corner cases.